# GPU RTX 3090 keeps of going into ERR after some usage

Tags: ubuntu, manjaro, python3, gpu, cuda

I have been struggling with some issue with a GPU I have on my machine. Currently the GPU works fine for some training work. But it goes into ERR when I type `nvidia-smi`. What happens then is that I have a python process which I cannot kill, not even with `sudo -kill 9 PID`. This is always accompanied by a core whose bar is 100% red in htop, not sure what that means.

If I try to restart the GPU, it tells me it cannot because the GPU is being used in other processes, which I guess are the ones I cannot kill. This happens consistently, if I reboot the problem seems solved, but again after a couple of training exercises the issue returns. The main issue is that most of the time I am connecting to my machine trough ssh, so if I reboot I have to ask someone  to turn back on my machine, or go myself.

The OS on my machine is Manjaro. But I had similar issues with Ubuntu 22.04, where I got

```
CUDA error: unspecified launch failure
```

I don't think it can be hardware related, as the GPU is one year old, and again it is able to train once restarted.

The specs of my machine are the following:

- CPU:  intel i9-13900K/KF 5.8GHz
- Motherboard: MSI PRO Z690-A DDR4
- RAM: 64GB DDR4 3200Mhz 2x32GB
- Power  supply: Corsair RM1000 80+ Gold Modular

The machine has also another GPU, which is an RTX 2080 TI.

Is there a fix to this problem? This is really worrying and problematic for workflow as you can imagine.

Best,
Luca

Comment: probably a typo but it's not `sudo -kill 9 PID` but `sudo kill -9 PID` even if you probably can run `sudo kill PID` only

Comment: Nope, same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think it can be hardware related, as the GPU is one year old, and again it is able to train once restarted.

It very well may be.

- Check/replace your PSU (in terms of voltages), reseat the GPU, check the temperatures, reconnect the power cable.
- Try installing/using the latest released drivers as well, which are 550.54.14 at the moment.
- Make sure you've asked the question here as well: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Comment: I have asked also there, still waiting for an answer. When you say hardware related, what do you think could be the cause? I would guess if the GPU is broken, then it would not work for any training. I will try those steps when I go back home in a month, as now I am travelling.  I will just avoid using it at all in the meantime. Also I don't think both of them can be broken at the same time, that would be highly unlikely. My current drivers are 545.29.06, with Cuda 12.3.

Comment: Please attach the result of running `sudo nvidia-bug-report.sh` after facing the issue to the topic you created on NVIDIA forums.

Comment: Now its running a big experiement on CPU, when its done likely tomorrow I will do it.

Comment: do you know of any potential hardware issue that could lead to this? I might also mention that if I don't touch the GPU the computer seems to works smoothly even under heavy loads

Comment: If it's a HW issue it could be down to either of a poor quality PSU, bad PCI-E connection, or overheating (bad thermal paste, or no cooling for RAM modules). I've outlined the steps you could take to eliminate everything. Lastly if I were you, I'd absolutely update the BIOS.

Comment: Thank you, I will for sure do all of them once I am phisically on my machine. I did monitor the temperatures and they did not seem problematic(around 80 celsius). I will also follow your suggestion and update the BIOS. Do you think there is a significant chance I will have to throw away my GPU? That would be disastrous given its very steep cost..